# Overwrite existing file in Java

Tags: java, filewriter

I have the following code that writes a text file and saves the numbers from the user input.

```
for (contador = 0; contador < numeros; contador++){
                array[contador]= Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa " + numeros + " números")); try{
                    File archivo = new File ("lista de numeros.txt");
                    FileWriter fr = new FileWriter (archivo,true);
                    fr.write(Integer.toString(array[contador]));
                    fr.write("\r\n");
                    fr.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error al escribir");
                }
```

What I want to do is to overwrite the file once is created not to append, however, if I change to false, it doesn't work because only saves the last number from user input.
Is there another way to overwrite the file? Or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Passing `false` _should_ be in fact rewriting the file. What do you mean with "it doesn't work because only saves the last number from user input"?

Comment: Lets say, the user enters 1,2,3,4,5. If its set in true, it saves the five numbers. But if I change to false it will only save the 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want something along the lines of the code below. File/FileWriter declaration outside the `try`, initialization inside the `try` and close in the `finally`.

```
File archivo = null;
FileWriter fr = null;
try {
    archivo = new File("lista de numeros.txt");
    fr = new FileWriter(archivo, true);
    for (contador = 0; contador < numeros; contador++) {
        array[contador] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa " + numeros + " números"));
        fr.write(Integer.toString(array[contador]));
        fr.write("\r\n");
    } 
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Error al escribir");
} finally {
  fr.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem and passing to _false_ to actually overwrite

Comment: @TiffanyM. Sure. Yes. That does seem plausible. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, delete the file before writing to it. Below there's a sample code of how you delete a file in Java:

```
try {
    Files.delete(path);
} catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
    System.err.format("%s: no such" + " file or directory%n", path);
} catch (DirectoryNotEmptyException x) {
    System.err.format("%s not empty%n", path);
} catch (IOException x) {
    // File permission problems are caught here.
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fr.close(); inside of **for**

```
File archivo = new File ("lista de numeros.txt");
    FileWriter fr = new FileWriter (archivo,true);

    for (contador = 0; contador < numeros; contador++){
        array[contador]= Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa " + numeros + " números")); try{        
            fr.write(Integer.toString(array[contador]));
            fr.write("\r\n");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error al escribir");
        }

    }
    fr.close();
```

The file must be closed after the process